# ¿Cómo sumar dos vectores dinámicos?

Tags: c++, array, funciones, buenas-prácticas

Hace una semana atrás he empezado a estudiar el tema de punteros y arrays dinámicos. Como practicando he hecho el siguiente programa que le permite al usuario sumar dos vectores del tamaño que él desee:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void leer_vector(int v[], int n)
{
    cout << "Ingrese los elementos del vector:\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];
}

void escribir_vector(int v[], int n)
{
    cout << "Los elementos del vector son:\t\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << v[i] << setw(5);
}

void sumar_vectores(int v1[], int v2[], int v3[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
}

int main()
{
    int dimension_vector;
    int *p_vector1, *p_vector2, *p_vector3;

    cout << "\250Cu\240ntos elementos desea ingresar?:\t";
    cin >> dimension_vector;
    cout << '\n';

    p_vector1 = new int[dimension_vector];
    p_vector2 = new int[dimension_vector];
    p_vector3 = new int[dimension_vector];

    leer_vector(p_vector1, dimension_vector);
    cout << '\n';
    leer_vector(p_vector2, dimension_vector);
    cout << '\n';
    escribir_vector(p_vector1, dimension_vector);
    cout << "\n\n";
    escribir_vector(p_vector2, dimension_vector);
    cout << "\n\n";

    p_vector3 = sumar_vectores(p_vector1, p_vector2, dimension_vector);
    escribir_vector(p_vector3, dimension_vector);
    cout << "\n\n";

    delete[] p_vector1;
    delete[] p_vector2;
    delete[] p_vector3; 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Mi duda es al momento de definir el procedimiento `void sumar_vectores` pues he utilizado cuatro parámetros y no me convence usar dicha cantidad de parámetros. Así que, por un lado, ¿es correcto utilizar más de tres parámetros en una función/procedimiento?. De acuerdo a está [respuesta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145073/286011), debería evitarse siempre que se pueda utilizar más de tres parámetros (así es como entiendo la respuesta).

Y si ese fuese el caso, ¿cómo podría modificar la definición del procedimiento `void sumar_vectores` de tal modo que utilice tres o menos parámetros?

Gracias de antemano por respuestas y/o comentarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dijo Jack *el destripador*, vamos por partes:

> ¿es correcto utilizar más de tres parámetros en una función/procedimiento?

Pues, como casi todo ... **depende**.

#### Factores lógicos.

En la respuesta que indicas, se están refiriendo a problemas *lógicos*; es decir, utilizar demasiados argumentos *puede indicar* un mal diseño de la función. Tal vez esa función esté realizando demasiado trabajo, y sería conveniente *dividirla* en varias funciones mas pequeñas.

Esto **no siempre es así**: algunas funciones, sencillamente, **necesitan** un determinado número de argumentos para funcionar (como tu propia función `sumar_vectores( )`.

No obstante, hay mecanismos para *facilitar el uso* de ese tipo de funciones; como indican en la propia respuesta, es muy común utilizar tipos de datos complejos, tales como `struct` (en C) o `class` (en C++).

Para no extendernos: en lugar de crear una función con 5 argumentos, creas una `struct` o `class` con 5 *campos*, la rellenas, y la pasas como **único** argumento.

#### Factores físicos

Esto es un punto de vista distinto. En determinadas arquitecturas, usar menos argumentos *puede* acelerar **la llamada** a la función.

Por ejemplo, en x86, la convención de llamada *fastcall* utiliza 3 registros (creo que eran 3, no estoy seguro) para pasar los 3 primeros argumentos, y el resto los coloca en la pila. En contraste, *cdecl* o *pascal* colocan **todos** los argumentos en la pila, por lo que son mas lentas. Por cierto, *fastcall* es la usada por defecto ;-)

Colocar en la pila es **mas lento** que usar registros, puesto que conlleva lecturas/escrituras en memória.

Pero ... estas cosas *tras el telón* no deberían preocuparte, salvo que estés escribiendo código crítico (en velocidad o tamaño), y puedes desentenderte de ellas el 99.99% de las veces. El compilador está para algo, y se encargará de optimizar el código tanto como pueda.

Además, C++ puede usar funciones `inline`, que **ni siquiera conllevan una verdadera llamada**. Vamos, que puedes no hacerle *ni caso* al tema físico ... aunque creo que conviene saberlo, ya que estamos tratando el asunto :-)

> ¿cómo podría modificar la definición del procedimiento void sumar_vectores de tal modo que utilice tres o menos parámetros?

Pues, como dije antes ... **depende**.

#### Estas en C++ ... ¡Usa clases!

En tu caso, podrías hacer

```
struct Vector {
  size_t m_size;
  int *ptr;
};
```

Lo anterior puede perfectamente usarse para lo que pretendes. Y, usando clases, te ahorras el último argumento de tu llamada, con lo que pasaría a tener solo 3 argumentos:

```
void sumar_vectores( const Vector &v1, const Vector &v2, Vector &v3 );
```

Y, ya que estamos, te reto a que implementes esto:

```
Vector sumar_vectores( const Vector &v1, const Vector &v2 );
```

Con lo que te ahorras otro mas; e incluso, *sobrecargando* el `operator+( )`:

```
Vector v3 = v1 + v1;
```

Con lo que sigues usando 2 argumentos, pero queda mas *bonito* :-)

#### ¿ Velocidad o tamaño ?

Otra forma de atacar tu caso concreto es **utilizar un valor especial para indicar el final del vector**; por ejemplo, usar `-1` como indicador.

Así, al rellenar, cuando el usuario termine de introducir, colocas *manualmente* un `-1` en el vector.

Ahora, también te puedes ahorrar el último argumento de tu función ... a costa de tener que calcular, **cada vez**, el tamaño del vector, contando los elementos hasta que llegues al `-1`.

Entonces, tu función quedaría

```
void sumar_vectores( int v1[], int v2[], int v3[] );
```

Claro que también podrías aprovechar la capacidad de las funciones de *retornar* cosas:

```
int *sumar_vectores( int v1[], int v2[] );
```

y te quedarías con solo 2.

#### Ya puestos ...

Siguiendo con tu caso concreto, aún podrías cambiar la lógica tras tus *vectores*; en tu código, el tamaño del vector está guardado en una variable a tal fin ... ¿ no puedes guardar ese tamaño en el propio vector ? Concretamente, en la posición `vector[0]`.

Con ello, tu función se queda igual que en el caso anterior:

```
int *sumar_vectores( int v1[], int v2[] );
```

Pero ahora no es necesario que calcules el tamaño en cada llamada ... a cambio, tus datos reales comienzan en la posición `vector[1]`.

Y la lógica de control de tus *vectores* se complica un poco; por ejemplo, para crear un *vector* de 7 elementos:

```
int *v7 = new int[8];
*v7 = 8; // Indicas el tamaño.
```

Ya para terminar y *rizar el rizo* un poco mas:

```
int *v7 = new int[8];
*v7 = 8; // Indicas el tamaño.
++v7;
```

Con este último paso, tu *vector* puede ser usado de forma *transparente* con otras funciones, pero tu sabras que, para obtener el tamaño, basta con hacer

```
int tam = *( v7 - 1 );
```

<sub>Ummm... creo que esta pregunta acabará cerrada por *basada en opiniones* o *demasiado amplia* :-O</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Con respecto a que mi pregunta sea cerrada, la verdad solo quería saber maneras alternativas de cómo definir el procedimiento `sumar_vectores`. La razón por la que puse el enlace y todo ese párrafo fue para motivar mi pregunta. En realidad, por ahora no me es tan importante discutir esas cuestiones a fondo. Al final me quedo con su última solución : `int *sumar_vectores` pues todavía no he estudiado ni estructuras ni clases.

Comment: Es broma, no creo que la cierren. Mi intención al escribirla es que fuera instructiva en varios aspectos. Espero haberlo conseguido, sin aburrir demasiado :-)

Comment: Ah jaja :P. Bueno, a mi me gustan las respuestas largas y detalladas y es por eso que no me he aburrido leyendo su respuesta.

Comment: Una consulta más, si no es una molestia. Al tratar de implementar la función `int* sumar_vectores(int v1[], int v2[], int n)`, he hecho `int *v3; v3 = new int[n]; ...; return v3;` y lo que quiero es añadir `delete[] v3;`, (ya que tengo entendido que por cada `new` se debe usar `delete`), pero no sé en que línea colocar dicha instrucción :(.

Comment: Déjalo dónde está. Los `delete`, cuando ya no necesites la memoria en cuestión.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Es correcto utilizar más de tres parámetros en una función/procedimiento?

No tiene nada de incorrecto, y tampoco tiene nada de correcto porque no es un problema de corrección. La respuesta que enlazas (de SoftwareEngineering) habla del libro [*Clean Code*](https://www.amazon.es/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) del [Tío Bob](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin) como referencia para determinar el número de parámetros de una función, pero hay varios motivos por lo que esa respuesta no tiene relación alguna con la corrección:

- *Clean Code* es un libro sobre escribir código claro y fácil de entender, no sobre escribir código correcto. El objetivo de este libro tiende a ser malinterpretado y el libro ha sido encumbrado inadecuadamente como biblia de la programación.
- La corrección del código no se puede establecer de manera universal ya que tiene una alta dependencia con el objetivo del código y factores externos: lo que es correcto en un contexto puede ser incorrecto en otro.

Como curiosidad, el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) indica en el Anexo B que los parámetros que puede recibir una función depende de la implementación del compilador pero que cómo mínimo deberían ser 256.

Si necesitas 256 parámetros en una función no significa que sea incorrecto<sup>1</sup>, pero hará que el código sea extremadamente difícil de entender.

#### No hay que volver a inventar la rueda.

La librería estándar de C++ ofrece un contenedor que está pensado precisamente para operaciones como las que estás haciendo: [`std::valarray`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray), puedes sumar dos `valarray` de la manera más natural posible, usando un símbolo de suma:

```
using intarray = std::valarray<int>;

intarray a({1, 2, 3, 4}), b({4, 3, 2, 1});
intarray c = a + b; // c contendra {5, 5, 5, 5}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Seguramente indica unas pobres decisiones de diseño y/o requerimientos absurdos.